# XML Data is sorted

Tags: java

I am constructing XML code using Java. See my code snippet.

```
    Document document = null;
    String xml = "";
    ReportsDAO objReportsDAO = null;
    try 
    {
        logger.info("Getting XML data for Consumable Report Starts...");
        objReportsDAO = new ReportsDAO();

        List consumableDTOLst = objReportsDAO.getConsumableData(issuedBy, issuedTo, employeeType, itemCode, itemName, className, transactionFromDate, transactionToDate, machineCode, workOrderNumber, jobName, customerId);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        document = builder.newDocument();
        Element rootElmnt = (Element) document.createElement("items");  
        document.appendChild(rootElmnt);

        Element elmt = null;
        ConsumableDTO objConsumableDTO = null;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        for (int i = 0; i < consumableDTOLst.size(); i++) 
        {
            objConsumableDTO = (ConsumableDTO)consumableDTOLst.get(i);
            elmt =  (Element) document.createElement("item");
            elmt.setAttribute("IssuedBy", objConsumableDTO.getIssuedBy());
            elmt.setAttribute("IssuedTo", objConsumableDTO.getIssuedTo());
            elmt.setAttribute("EMPLOYECADRE", objConsumableDTO.getEmployeeType());
            elmt.setAttribute("ITEMCODE", objConsumableDTO.getItemCode());
            elmt.setAttribute("ITEMNAME", objConsumableDTO.getItemName());
            elmt.setAttribute("ITEMCLASS", objConsumableDTO.getClassName());
            elmt.setAttribute("DATE", sdf.format(objConsumableDTO.getTransactionDate()));
            elmt.setAttribute("machineCode", objConsumableDTO.getMachineCode());
            elmt.setAttribute("JOB", objConsumableDTO.getJobName());
            elmt.setAttribute("WORKORDERNUMBER", objConsumableDTO.getWorkOrderNumber());
            elmt.setAttribute("CustomerName", objConsumableDTO.getCustomerName());
            elmt.setAttribute("RoleName", objConsumableDTO.getGroupName());
            elmt.setAttribute("VendorName", objConsumableDTO.getVendorName());
            elmt.setAttribute("QTY", String.valueOf(Math.abs(objConsumableDTO.getQuantity())));
            elmt.setAttribute("unitDescription", objConsumableDTO.getUnitDescription());
            elmt.setAttribute("RATEPERQTY", String.valueOf(objConsumableDTO.getRate()));
            elmt.setAttribute("AMOUNT", String.valueOf(objConsumableDTO.getAmount()));
            rootElmnt.appendChild(elmt);
        }
```

The problem is all the attributes are sorted automatically. How to restrict it?

For eg,

```
<empdetails age="25" name="john"/>
```

but i want

```
<empdetails name="john" age="25"/>
```

Please suggest some idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Duplicate: [Order of XML attributes after DOM processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726395/order-of-xml-attributes-after-dom-processing)

From [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726395/order-of-xml-attributes-after-dom-processing/726933#726933):

> Look at section 3.1 of the XML
>   recommendation. It says, "Note that
>   the order of attribute specifications
>   in a start-tag or empty-element tag is
>   not significant."
>
> If a piece of software requires
>   attributes on an XML element to appear
>   in a specific order, that software is
>   not processing XML, it's processing
>   text that looks superficially like
>   XML. It needs to be fixed.
>
> If it can't be fixed, and you have to
>   produce files that conform to its
>   requirements, you can't reliably use
>   standard XML tools to produce those
>   files.

Credit to [Robert Rossney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19403/robert-rossney)

Answer (score 0):

XML attributes are *not* ordered. How they're output is dependent on the XML output mechanism you use.

Consequently you could write your on output mechanism, but you shouldn't rely on any consumer to consume them in an ordered fashion. If you want/need ordering, you should instead specify a sequence of XML elements below this node.