# XML parser-writer that keeps Attributes order

Tags: python, xml

I need to parse XML document and then write every node to separate files keeping exact order of attributes.
So if i have input file like :

```
<item a="a" b="b" c="c"/>
<item a="a1" b="b2" c="c3"/>
```

Output should be 2 files with  every item. 
Now if xml.dom.minidom is used - attribute order is changed in output( i can get - `<item b="b" c="c" **a="a"**/>`)

I found pxdom lib, it keeps order but very-very slow( minidom parsing takes 0.08 sec., pxdom parsing takes 2,5 sec.)

Is there any other python libraries that can keep attributes?

UPD: libarry should also keep upper and lower cases. So "Item" is not equal to "item"

Comment: The general consensus is that attribute order doesn't matter. Why do you need to keep them ordered?

Comment: That's not my wish) Unfortunately airfare's GDS ( global distibution system) i'm working with requires exact match of attribute order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726395/order-of-xml-attributes-after-dom-processing) useful. Bottom line summary-- standard xml tools and libraries most likely won't be able to do this.

Comment: thanks, i saw that Q, pxdom does it but very very slow. in general problem is to find some library that uses list(instead of dict) as a storage for attrs

Comment: A library that does this would have to store both a dict and a list, for both the mapping and the order. Or possibly an OrderedDict. I tried this scenario with `lxml` before posting this answer, and no matter how many attributes I added, the keys *were* always in the order as listed in the xml file. But I have no idea if that is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as soup

>>> html = '''<item a="a" b="b" c="c"/>
<item a="a1" b="b2" c="c3"/>'''
>>> s = soup(html)
>>> s.findAll('item')
[<item a="a" b="b" c="c"></item>, <item a="a1" b="b2" c="c3"></item>]
```

Comment: unfortunately BeautifulSoup changes all nodes to the lower case. and it seems that beatifulsoup cannot be case sensetive

Comment: you can keep the letter case by selecting to parse with XML: e.g. s = soup(html,"xml")