# DOMsource is changing order of XML attributes

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have used `DOMsorce` for `XML` modification when i am writing modified data to a new file it is changing actual  order of attributes(ascending order). so how to control this modification.

Comment: how are you writing the data?

Comment: It may help you [order-of-xml-attributes-after-dom-processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726395/order-of-xml-attributes-after-dom-processing)

Comment: There's no significance to the order of attributes in XML - `<a att2="2" att1="1"/>` is the same as `<a att1="1" att2="2"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a quite similar problem. I need to have always the same attribute for first.
Example :

```
<h50row a="1" xidx="1" c="1"></h50row>
<h50row a="2" b="2" xidx="2"></h50row>
```

must become

```
<h50row xidx="1" a="1" c="1"></h50row>
<h50row xidx="2" a="2" b="2"></h50row>
```

I found a solution with a regex:

```
test = "<h50row a=\"1\" xidx=\"1\" c=\"1\"></h50row>";
test = test.replaceAll("(<h5.*row)(.*)(.xidx=\"\\w*\")([^>]*)(>)", "$1$3$2$4$5");
```

Hope you find this usefull