# Python Exclusive XML Canonicalization (xml-exc-c14n)

Tags: python, xml

In Python, I need to Canonicalize (c14n) an XML string.

Which module/package can I use for this? And how should I do this?

(I prefer to use default python 2.7 modules, without extra installs or patches.)

For reference see: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-exc-c14n/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from http://www.decalage.info/en/python/lxml-c14n

> [lxml](http://lxml.de/) provides a very easy way to do c14n in python.
>   <..>
>
> Here is an example showing how to perform C14N using lxml 2.1:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
et = ET.parse('file.xml')
output = StringIO.StringIO()
et.write_c14n(output)
print output.getvalue()
```

from lxml docs:

> [write_c14n](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#write_c14n)(self, file, **exclusive=False**, with_comments=True,
>   compression=0, inclusive_ns_prefixes=None)
>
> C14N write of document. Always writes UTF-8.
>
> <..>

Also there is libxml2:

> XML C14N version 1.0 provides two options which make four
>   possibilities (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n and
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-exc-c14n/):
>
> - Inclusive or Exclusive C14N
> - With or without comments
>
> libxml2 gives access to these options in its C14N API:
>   http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-c14n.html

Though obligatory check for version changes in these two libs.

Comment: I previously tried this and then it failed, so I figured it was a patch / other version than I had. Now I found out the actually works! Thanks for pointing it out once more!

Comment: Wow, that really was easy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is failing with error - `NameError: name 'StringIO' is not defined`

Comment: @BrunoGelb should update accepted answer since in lxml documentation under write_c14n method:
```NOTE: This method is deprecated as of lxml 4.4 and will be removed in a future release. Use .write(f, method="c14n") instead.```

Answer (score 0):

now in python 3 you can write your code like this:

```py
import lxml.etree as ET

et = ET.parse('your_xml_file_that_you_want_to_canonicalize.xml')
et.write_c14n("your_result_will_be_in_this_file.xml")
```