# find and replace an int in xml file

Tags: java, xml, replace, find

I have a issue where i need to find and replace an int within a xml file.

Here is an example file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
<Element time="0.00000" num="10723465" />
<Element time="7.98000" num="10028736" />
<Element time="8.40000" num="94123576" />
</data>
```

I want to find and replace the "num" attribute. I have been able to do this with the `DOM` factory however it doesn't keep the order of the attributes. There must be a simpler way to find and replace the `num`. any help would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advice 1: you should use XML library to parse, nothing else, or it would be a pain.

Information 2: order doesnt matter in XML for attributes. Then you should forget this problem:

See this with much more details
[Order of XML attributes after DOM processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726395/order-of-xml-attributes-after-dom-processing)

Alternative: use Regex (it can work for very simple XML). example in the link before

Comment: yeah i understand the order doesn't matter usually but where i am using this xml the order is important for me :)

Comment: or regex : some posts exist